# Python Scipy and Networkx: How to compute a Euclidean distance matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, networkx

I am using Python **Networkx** to build a graph and I have the following node positions as an example (positions.txt):

```
1 21.5 23
2 24.5 20
3 19.5 19
4 22.5 15
5 24.5 12
```

Node ID, X, Y. I read the file using Pandas and set the positions as node attributes in Networkx. Nodes are added using `add_edge(id1, id2, weight)` method in a `for` loop (with no self edges). So far, I have assumed that all the nodes are connected to each other by default and have not taken parameters such as Radius or Distance of nodes into consideration.
Now, I want to compute a Euclidean radius or distance matrix between the nodes using these node positions, and with this matrix I want to be able to print the neighbours of a node that fall within a given radius `n` and save the file as a csv matrix file. A friend suggested that I use `scipy`'s `euclidean` method but I have no clue how to use this to build the matrix, hence I have no starting point. I tried using `ego_graph()` but it did not give me the desired results.
Any help is appreciated in solving my problem.
Thanks in advance. (Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM and Python 2.7)

Comment: The distance for the node pair (i, j) is the same as for (j, i) and obviously if one is within range, so will be the other. When you save your data, do you want both results?

Comment: @Reti43 that's a good point you made. If both the results are saved, then it would become a Matrix surely. And I assume if I save only one result then it will be like an edge list. It would be best if I could have both so that later I can choose which is best for my experiments.

Comment: One more question, even though it might be irrelevant. What's the meaning of `add_edge(id1, id2, weight)` for adding nodes? You can simple add a node with `add_node()` and then set the position as an attribute, just like you described one sentence before.

Comment: I am using 2 `for` loops to add nodes in `add_edge()` instead of using `add_node()` several times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) to generate your distance matrix given a list of coordinates.

Obviously a numpy array is always 0-indexed and if your nodes have random numbers, you want to keep a list of them to know which row/column of your matrix corresponds to which pair.

What you do after that should be trivial, but I'll give an example based on your description. For each node, print the id of said node and the ids of any neighbouring nodes within your threshold distance.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

def neighbour_nodes_of(node, dist_matrix, distance):
    row = dist_matrix[node]
    return np.where((row <= distance) * (row > 0))[0]

ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
coords = [(21.5, 23),
          (24.5, 20),
          (19.5, 19),
          (22.5, 15),
          (24.5, 12),
          ]
threshold = 8.

dist_matrix = distance.cdist(coords, coords)

# this is something you can write to a file instead
for i, node_id in enumerate(ids):
    neighbours = neighbour_nodes_of(i, dist_matrix, threshold)
    neighbour_ids = [ids[n] for n in neighbours]
    print([node_id] + neighbour_ids)
```

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity (and a little bit of necessity), I had another question: I am running the `nx.draw` and `plt.show()` in loops so as to recreate the addition and removal of edges in the graph (like a movie). But the loops cause the output to overlap all edges and nodes from previous iterations and blotches the output which is not desired. Do you know a way/method to "redraw" the graph at every iteration so as to avoid the above problem? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @MFHS there are various methods for animation display, the crudest of them being to call `plt.cla()` within each loop to clear the current axes.  (you might also need a call to `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()`).  This is typically ok if you just need to inspect a short sequence but gets increasingly laggy with more redraws.  For more alternatives, see [animation API](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html)